# Copy/duplicate current keymap to modify the copied one

Tags: interface, shortcut, keymap

Quick question, is there a way to copy/duplicate my current keymap and then modify the duplicated one for a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can <kbd>Import</kbd> and <kbd>Export</kbd> keymaps from the buttons at the top of the Preferences dialog:

[image]

You can also add a preset to the dropdown by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> icon:

[image]

and enter a name for your new preset:

[image]

Then <kbd>Save</kbd> the preferences as usual:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easier way to toggle between two keymaps rather than importing and exporting?

Comment: Set up your own preset and add it as I suggested above. That way it stays with the Blender installation and you can toggle between yours and the default Blender one.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work for me if I toogle my preset and the default, I have to import every time for it to not change the default.

Comment: Ok, seems to work now. Mabye I was tired yesterday! Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got there in the end! :^)